# javacript string literal unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, string, literals

Anyone could explain why the console logs below produce different output while I expected them to be exactly the same?

```
'use strict';

const objectSelected = document.querySelector('.message');

console.log(`${objectSelected}`);
console.log(objectSelected);
```

Comment: What did you expect, what do the two lines actually output?

Comment: 0


First console.log returns "object HTMLParagraphElement" - kind of like almost if I asked for typeof (thought typeof returns an object), second one - Content

- but if I understand what IS actually in console at this point is the whole CSS formatted object - so the html content I see is wrapped in all the things I don't see... but these are there. Am I right?

Comment: The literal format evaluates the variable as string, what you have is a dom element reference, so it essetially evaluates to objectSelected.toString() and you see the response "object HTMLParagraphElement" which is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console will log any type of value: objects, arrays, functions, booleans, numbers, etc. Any time you put a non-string inside a string or concatenate a non-string with a string, JavaScript will call `.toString()` on the the thing which is not a string:

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar' }
console.log(obj)             //-> { foo: "bar" }
console.log(obj.toString()). //-> "[object Object]"
console.log('' + obj).       //-> "[object Object]"
console.log(`${obj}`).       //-> "[object Object]"
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing an object in a string template, it will be converted to a string. That's why the first statement will result in `[object <something>]`.

The second will print the value as is (as an object). When passing an object to console.log, it will be printed as the full object.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is designed to show detailed information about an object if you log an object. It doesn't just call an object's `toString` method (which is implicitly called if you try to use an object in a context that expects a string).